# Is LTE-M better than NB-IoT for low data rate Mobile applications? Why?

Tags: lte

If there were a mobile IoT device needing only a low data rate and not needing low latency, would NB-IoT be a good connectivity option? Would LTE-M be better?

‘Mobile’ is key here. A device that will physically move many kilometres.

(Assuming both LTE-M and NB-IoT were available in the relevant geographies, and that the module to be deployed would support only one of NB-IoT or LTE-M.)

I’ve seen statements that LTE-M is better for mobile applications, but I can’t find info on why it would be better in the situation described above.

Comment: Radio access wise, LTE-M is designed with smaller latency and, therefore, is better suited for applications requiring mobility. There are also assumptions and implementations at protocol levels, e.g. only cell reselection for NB-IoT. Just search for "3GPP eMTC applications".

Comment: For example, (2017, but still good) https://www.qualcomm.com/system/files/document/files/leading_the_lte_iot_evolution_to_connect_the_massive_iot_0.pdf

Comment: Thanks @AlexTP helpful link